# Find domain and range of given function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to find the domain and range of function $$f(x)= \arcsin({x^2 +1}/{x^2 +2})$$

**My try**

Domain $$({x^2 +1}/{x^2 +2})= 1- 1/{x^2 +2}$$
As $1/{x^2+2}$ always lies between $0$ to $1$ for all $x$,$1- 1/{x^2 +2}$ lies in(0,1), domain lies for all real numbers.
But I didn't get any idea for range.

Comment: The domain is empty. For any $x\neq 0$, $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\geq 2$ by the AM-GM inequality, and the arcsine function is not defined over the interval $(3,+\infty)$.

Comment: I have edited the question please verify it sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}+2}$ = 1- $\frac{1}{x^{2}+2}$ ,x$^{2}$$\geq$
0 $\Longrightarrow$$\frac{1}{2}$$\leq$ $\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}+2}$<
1 and$ $domain of sin$^{-1}$x =[-1,1]

[-1,1] $\cap$ [$\frac{1}{2}$, 1) = [$\frac{1}{2}$,1) $\Longrightarrow$
$\frac{1}{2}$$\leq$ $\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}+2}$< 1 $\Longrightarrow$0
< $\frac{1}{x^{2}+2}$ $\leq$$\frac{1}{2}$ is true $\forall$ x
$\in$$\mathbb{R}$

Hence the Domain is $\mathbb{R}$

**Range** $\Longrightarrow$$\frac{1}{2}$$\leq$
$\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}+2}$< 1 $\Longrightarrow$ sin$^{-1}$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$\leq$sin$^{-1}$$\left(\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}+2}\right)$<
sin$^{-1}$0

$\Longrightarrow$

Range= [ $\frac{\text{ {$\pi$}}}{6}$,$\pi$)